# Sample implementation of Transport-level security for Oracle Service Bus (OSB)

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, osb

I have a custom authentication library external to OSB.

How can I secure transport channel (JMS/EJB/etc) using external Java api. Is there some sample implementation of this out there. The version I'm currently using is 11g.